# How Would Someone Become the king of the pirate?

Tags: one-piece

Can someone become the king of the pirates only by finding the one piece.

Comment: You become the pirate king when you reach Raftel.

Comment: you mean laugh tale and i don't think thats all you need to do to become king of the pirates

Answer (score 1):

1. Be the strongest. ( Late Roger was the strongest pirate in his era at peak, Late Whitebeard was the closest to Roger's strength )
2. Get to the end of the grand line aka Laugh tale. (Roger was the first person to conquer the grandline so he was given nickname "Pirate king".)

Also it is not a title it was just a nickname to separate him from pirates weaker than him.

Comment: your answer is nice and all, but it kinda needs sources from the manga/anime.